# XPATH throwing java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, xml, maven, xpath

I want `CONFIDENTIAL` as my desired output.

My Program

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        try {
            XmlObject xoobj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(file);
            var declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' ";
            final String xpathFilter = "data(//v:shape[contains(@id,'PowerPlusWaterMarkObject')]/v:textpath/@string)";

            XmlObject[] arr = xoobj.selectPath(declareNameSpaces + xpathFilter);
            System.out.println(arr[0].toString());
        } catch (XmlException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

test.xml

```
<xml-fragment
        xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d"
        xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
        xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
        xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
        xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
        xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
        xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
        xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
    <w:sdtPr>
        <w:id w:val="-1126775779"/>
        <w:docPartObj>
            <w:docPartGallery w:val="Watermarks"/>
            <w:docPartUnique/>
        </w:docPartObj>
    </w:sdtPr>
    <w:sdtContent>
        <w:p w14:paraId="41319DAD" w14:textId="4534348F" w:rsidR="006868D8" w:rsidRDefault="006868D8">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Header"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:noProof/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:pict w14:anchorId="63C3AA3C">
                    <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t136" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="136" adj="10800" path="m@7,l@8,m@5,21600l@6,21600e">
                        <v:formulas>
                            <v:f eqn="sum #0 0 10800"/>
                            <v:f eqn="prod #0 2 1"/>
                            <v:f eqn="sum 21600 0 @1"/>
                            <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @2"/>
                            <v:f eqn="sum 21600 0 @3"/>
                            <v:f eqn="if @0 @3 0"/>
                            <v:f eqn="if @0 21600 @1"/>
                            <v:f eqn="if @0 0 @2"/>
                            <v:f eqn="if @0 @4 21600"/>
                            <v:f eqn="mid @5 @6"/>
                            <v:f eqn="mid @8 @5"/>
                            <v:f eqn="mid @7 @8"/>
                            <v:f eqn="mid @6 @7"/>
                            <v:f eqn="sum @6 0 @5"/>
                        </v:formulas>
                        <v:path textpathok="t" o:connecttype="custom" o:connectlocs="@9,0;@10,10800;@11,21600;@12,10800" o:connectangles="270,180,90,0"/>
                        <v:textpath on="t" fitshape="t"/>
                        <v:handles>
                            <v:h position="#0,bottomRight" xrange="6629,14971"/>
                        </v:handles>
                        <o:lock v:ext="edit" text="t" shapetype="t"/>
                    </v:shapetype>
                    <v:shape id="PowerPlusWaterMarkObject357476642" o:spid="_x0000_s1025" type="#_x0000_t136" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:527.85pt;height:131.95pt;rotation:315;z-index:-251657216;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin" o:allowincell="f" fillcolor="silver" stroked="f">
                        <v:fill opacity=".5"/>
                        <v:textpath style="font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;;font-size:1pt" string="CONFIDENTIAL"/>
                        <w10:wrap anchorx="margin" anchory="margin"/>
                    </v:shape>
                </w:pict>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
    </w:sdtContent>
</xml-fragment>
```

Output

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.13.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -javaagent:/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3F078016-ECB8-463C-BEBA-5701DF97E1A5/d/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=54386:/private/var/folders/5_/5blqbh750wsc9pc01bn0lgph0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3F078016-ECB8-463C-BEBA-5701DF97E1A5/d/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/sahibyar/Dailytasks/test-project/target/classes:/Users/sahibyar/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/3.1.0/xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar:/Users/sahibyar/.m2/repository/org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans-xpath/2.4.0/xmlbeans-xpath-2.4.0.jar:/Users/sahibyar/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/saxon/8.5.1/saxon-8.5.1.jar:/Users/sahibyar/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/saxon-xpath/8.7/saxon-xpath-8.7.jar:/Users/sahibyar/.m2/repository/net/sf/saxon/saxon-dom/8.7/saxon-dom-8.7.jar main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:  Trying XBeans path engine... Trying XQRL... Trying XDK... Trying delegated path engine... FAILED on declare namespace v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' data(//v:shape[contains(@id,'PowerPlusWaterMarkObject')]/v:textpath/@string)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:217)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Path.getCompiledPath(Path.java:143)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._selectPath(Cursor.java:902)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.selectPath(Cursor.java:2634)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:476)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.selectPath(XmlObjectBase.java:460)
    at main.main(main.java:14)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following XPath resolved, my problem.

```
final var xpathFilter = "*//v:shape/v:textpath/@string"
```

Answer (score 0):

`declare namespace` can be done in XQuery but not in XPath so either use an XQuery processor like BaseX or Saxon 10 or 9 or study the API of your chosen XPath processor, for XPath there is usually an API method to bind prefixes to namespace URIs so that you can use the prefixes in your XPath expressions.

Answer (score 0):

XMLBeans doesn't support complex XPaths by default including the `data()` method and predicate filters etc. To support these features it relies on `Saxon` to be present in classpath.

> For **XMLBeans 3.x.x**, we'll need to manually download [Saxon
> 9.0.0.4j](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/saxon/saxonb9-0-0-4j.zip?download) and add it to classpath
>
> For **XMLBeans 5.x.x** (Latest), we'll need `Saxon-HE 10.x` which we
> can directly add it to our pom file as follows
>
> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
>         <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
>         <version>5.0.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
>         <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
>         <version>2.14.1</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
>         <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
>         <version>10.6</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```
>
> *Source : https://xmlbeans.apache.org/documentation/conInstallGuide.html*

Secondly, we'll need to replace - either manually or in code before parsing - the root `<xml-fragment>` starting and ending tag with some other tag name like `<root>` because otherwise XMLBeans will parse it as a `document fragment` being the root node schema type instead of `document` type and XPaths with predicates won't work.

Finally, assuming we have Saxon added and dealt with `<xml-fragment/>` tag. To get the `CONFIDENTIAL` value as output, we just need to cast the result to `SimpleValue` and call `getStringValue()`on it.

Here is the modified

```
import org.apache.xmlbeans.SimpleValue;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("test.xml");
        try {
            XmlObject xoobj = XmlObject.Factory.parse(file);
            var declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' ";
            final String xpathFilter = "data(//v:shape[contains(@id,'PowerPlusWaterMarkObject')]/v:textpath/@string)";

            XmlObject[] arr = xoobj.selectPath(declareNameSpaces + xpathFilter);
            
            //Cast to SimpleValue
            SimpleValue result = (SimpleValue) arr[0];
            System.out.println(result.getStringValue());

        } catch (XmlException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```